# Java & Eclipse :: Eclipse Doesn't Recognize Common Packages in an Imported Project

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, package

I have what is probably a stupid question... but here goes anyway.  Some years back, I wrote a "Star Trek" game in Java 8, using JavaFX and Eclipse IDE.  The project grew to be fairly large, but it worked.  When I finished, I made sure to export the project using Eclipse's `File --> Export` menu.

I recently grew nostalgic and decided to import the "Trek" project into Eclipse on my current laptop.  (The original laptop died.)  FYI, my current version of Eclipse is Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0), which I thought was pretty recent.

The project imported just fine, but Eclipse seems mystified by everything in it.  For example, when I try to compile and run the project, this error comes up immediately:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class gameEngine.MainEventTrek
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gameEngine.MainEventTrek
```

`gameEngine.MainEventTrek` contains the project's `main()` method.  Eclipse can't find it???  But the java file is right there, right in the project's `src` directory:

[image]

That's not all.  When I open the Java files, Eclipse seems ignorant of how to import common packages:

[image]

Look at that; Even line 1 has an error!  (`"The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"`)  I can understand that Eclipse might not know about JavaFX - I can't remember if I installed it - but Eclipse doesn't seem to know about common packages like `java.math` and `java.util`.  Heck, later in my code, Eclipse doesn't know what the `System` package is, so all my `System.out.println()` commands are now throwing errors.

I'm a fairly good Java coder, but I'm pretty stupid when it comes to resolving basic compiler issues like this.  Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be and how I go about fixing this?  Thanks... and Live Long and Prosper.

Comment: The red exclamation mark indicates that there are problems with your project configuration. Your screenshot shows that you are using a pretty outdated Eclipse. Using the current Eclipse with an embedded Java would probably be the solution, or at least part of the solution.

Comment: @howlger Innnnnnnnnnteresting!  I am using Eclipse Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0), which I assumed was pretty recent.  I'll edit the original post to include that information, thanks!

Comment: 2018-12 (4.10.0) is more than three years and 13 releases behind. It's too old to be able to understand more recent Java versions.

Comment: @howlger Good point, thank you!  So I wrote the original code in 2017, on what was the latest version of Eclipse at the time.  Do you think its naïve to suppose that Eclipse 2018 should automatically be able to support 2017 code?  No wrong answers, I'm interested in your general impression.  Thanks!

Comment: Since Java 9 there is no 100% backwards compatibility due things were removed from the system library, also JavaFX. So you either have to install a Java 8 JDK (from e.g. https://adoptium.net/) and configure it in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_ or add JavaFX as a dependency (see https://openjfx.io/).